# Azure synapse workspace through powershell (resume/suspend)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-synapse

Here is my script.

```
# Install and import the Az module if not already installed
if (-not (Get-Module -Name Az -ListAvailable)) {
    Install-Module -Name Az -Force -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser
}
Import-Module Az -Force

# Function to suspend the SQL pool
function Suspend-SqlPool {
    param (
        [string]$ResourceGroupName,
        [string]$WorkspaceName,
        [string]$SqlPoolName
    )

    try {
        Suspend-AzSynapseSqlPool -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -WorkspaceName $WorkspaceName -Name $SqlPoolName
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Error suspending SQL Pool $($SqlPoolName): $_"
    }
}

# Function to resume the SQL pool
function Resume-SqlPool {
    param (
        [string]$ResourceGroupName,
        [string]$WorkspaceName,
        [string]$SqlPoolName
    )

    try {
        Resume-AzSynapseSqlPool -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -WorkspaceName $WorkspaceName -Name $SqlPoolName
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Error resuming SQL Pool $($SqlPoolName): $_"
    }
}

# Sign in to your Azure account
$null = Connect-AzAccount -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Specify the subscription ID you want to work with
$targetSubscriptionId = "my subscription"  # Replace with your actual subscription ID

# Set the specified subscription as the current context
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $targetSubscriptionId

# Get all Synapse workspaces in the selected subscription
$SynapseWorkspace = Get-AzSynapseWorkspace

Write-Output "Synapse Workspace Name: $($SynapseWorkspace.Name)"
Write-Output "Managed Resource Group: $($SynapseWorkspace.ManagedResourceGroupName)"
Write-Output "Resource Group: $($SynapseWorkspace.ResourceGroupName)"
Write-Output "Resource ID: $($SynapseWorkspace.Id)"

# Variables
# resource group
$rg = "rg-tms-synapse-tst-weu"

# Getting SQL pool names
$SqlPools = Get-AzSynapseSqlPool -WorkspaceName $SynapseWorkspace.Name

# ================ Time variables
$suspensionStart = "15:55"
$suspensionEnd = "15:56"
$resumeStart = "17:10"
$resumeEnd = "17:11"


# Additional conditions
$currentTime = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm"
$dayOfWeek = (Get-Date).DayOfWeek

# Loop to suspend or resume individual SQL pools based on their current state
foreach ($sqlpool in $SqlPools) {
    # Check the current state of the SQL pool
    $currentState = $sqlpool.Status

    # Start the timer
    $timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

    Write-Output "Processing SQL Pool $($sqlpool.SqlPoolName). Current state: $($currentState), Day of week: $($dayOfWeek), Current time: $($currentTime)"


    if ($currentState -eq "Online" -and $dayOfWeek -ne "Saturday" -and $dayOfWeek -ne "Sunday" -and $currentTime -ge $suspensionStart -and $currentTime -lt $suspensionEnd) {
        Suspend-SqlPool -ResourceGroupName $rg -WorkspaceName $SynapseWorkspace.Name -SqlPoolName $sqlpool.SqlPoolName
        Write-Output "SQL Pool $($sqlpool.SqlPoolName) is suspended."
        Write-Output $dayOfWeek

    }
    elseif ($currentState -eq "Paused" -and $dayOfWeek -ne "Saturday" -and $dayOfWeek -ne "Sunday" -and $currentTime -ge $resumeStart -and $currentTime -lt $resumeEnd) {

        Resume-SqlPool -ResourceGroupName $rg -WorkspaceName $SynapseWorkspace.Name -SqlPoolName $sqlpool.SqlPoolName
        Write-Output "SQL Pool $($sqlpool.SqlPoolName) is resumed."
        Write-Output $dayOfWeek

    }
    else {
        # Handle other states if needed
        Write-Output "SQL Pool $($sqlpool.SqlPoolName) is in an unexpected state: $($sqlpool.Status)"
    }

    # Stop the timer and get the elapsed time
    $timer.Stop()
    $elapsedTime = $timer.Elapsed  

    # Output the elapsed time
    Write-Output "Elapsed time: $($elapsedTime.ToString())"
}
```

**And here is the result**

> ```
> Processing SQL Pool syndptmststweu01. Current state: Online, Day of week: thursday, Current time: 16:19
>
> SQL Pool syndptmststweu01 is in an unexpected state: Online
>
> Elapsed time: 00:00:00.0041932
>
> Processing SQL Pool test_sqlpool. Current state: Online, Day of week: thursday, Current time: 16:19
>
> SQL Pool test_sqlpool is in an unexpected state: Online
>
> Elapsed time: 00:00:00.0033260
> ```

**---------------**

Everything works fine but the moment I put the time in the condition it does not work and jumps directly to the last block of **else** although the status is **online**

What am I doing wrong? the moment I put the time it does not work.

My goal is to **suspend** azure synapse workspace everyday at 20h00 and **resume** at 6h00

Comment: you can directly compare the current time with your target suspension and resume times using TimeSpan objects this might work for your issue. @bizimunda